# Body of "If let" not working when trying to downcast TableViewController

Tags: swift, xcode

```swift
import Foundation
import UIKit
import GoogleSignIn

class Switcher {
    
    static func updateRootVC(){
        let viewModel = ContactTableViewModelFromEntry.init()
        let service = GoogleService().shared
        var rootVC : UIViewController?
      
        guard let hasPrevSignIn = service?.hasPreviousSignIn() else { return }
        if hasPrevSignIn {
            
            if let contactVC = UIStoryboard(name: Constants.kStoryboardName, bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: Constants.kRootId) as? ContactTableViewController {

                service?.restorePreviousSignIn()
                rootVC = contactVC
                contactVC.viewModel = viewModel
            }

              }
              else {
                rootVC = UIStoryboard(name: Constants.kStoryboardName, bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: Constants.kLoginId)
              }
        
        let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
        appDelegate.window?.rootViewController = rootVC
    }
}
```

These things are never executing:

- service?.restorePreviousSignIn()
- rootVC = contactVC
- contactVC.viewModel = viewModel

Can someone help me?

Comment: Would you mind printing `UIStoryboard(name: Constants.kStoryboardName, bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: Constants.kRootId)`? If might fail because it's not a `ContactTableViewController`. As to why, we can't really know. Did you failed to set the class?

Comment: w/o "if let" it is working fine: `let contactVC = UIStoryboard(name: Constants.kStoryboardName, bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: Constants.kRootId)` but I need to set viewModel for ContactTableViewController

Comment: It's the cast, and that's not what I asked. Either show us in Storyboard the real class of the ViewController with identifier `Constants.kRootId`, or print the value as I said, it should print the real class of the instance. Or force it: `let vc = UIStoryboard(name: Constants.kStoryboardName, bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: Constants.kRootId) as! ContactTableViewController` and show us the crash error message in console

Comment: @Larme Thank you very much! kRootId is wrong identifier, it is for navigationcontroller, not for ContactTableViewController.

Comment: Just a note that it's easier to debug things if you don't try to perform 3 different operations in one line of code.